# registration page with php and mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to create a registration page that adds new users to a database with php, i can't seem to get the information to add to the database, it is most likely something stupid that I have doing wrong or have missed out in my code.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />


    <title></title>
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />


        <script src="boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/party.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery_min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/cookies.js"></script>


</head>

<body>




<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div id="container_register">

<div id="content_register">

    <h2>Register</h2>

    <?php
include "connect.php";
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array(); //Declare An Array to store any error message

    if (empty($_POST['up_username'])) { //if no name has been supplied
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name '; //add to array "error"
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['up_username']; //else assign it a variable

    }

    if (empty($_POST['up_email'])) {

        $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';

    } else {

if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",

            $_POST['up_email'])) {

            //regular expression for email validation

            $Email = $_POST['up_email'];

        } else {

            $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';

        }

 }


    if (empty($_POST['up_password'])) {

        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';

    } else {

        $Password = $_POST['up_password'];

    }

if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '



{ // If everything's OK...



        // Make sure the email address is available:

        $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE Email ='$Email'";

        $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);

        if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)

            echo ' Database Error Occured ';

        }
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .



            // Create a unique  activation code:


            $query_insert_user =

                "INSERT INTO `users` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password')";


$result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);

            if (!$result_insert_user) {

                echo 'Query Failed ';

            }

 echo '<div class="success">Thank you for

registering! </div>';

             } else { // If it did not run OK.
                echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a systemdiv>';

            }


        } else { // The email address is not available.

            echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email address has already been registered.</div>';

        }



    } else { //If the "error" array contains error msg , display them



        echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';

        foreach ($error as $key => $values) {



            echo '  <li>' . $values . '</li>';



        }

        echo '</ol></div>';



    }



    mysqli_close($dbc); //Close the DB Connection

// End of the main Submit conditional.
    ?>

        <form name="signup" id="signup" action="register.php" method="post">

            <label for="up_username"><span class="required">*</span> Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="up_username" id="up_username" placeholder="First Surname" />

<br>
            <label for="up_email"><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="up_email" id="up_email" placeholder="username@email.com" />

<br>
            <label for="up_password"><span class="required">*</span> Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="up_password" id="up_password" />

<br>
            <label for="up_password_c"><span class="required">*</span> Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="up_password_c" id="up_password_c" />


            <div class="div_submit">

                <input id="register_submit" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
            </div>

        </form><!--#sign up end-->

    <p class="required">* Indicates a required field</p>

</div><!--content div end-->

</div><!--container div end-->
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: an idea of what it is doing - all be it erroneously - would be nice...

Comment: What part of this is not working? Have you done anything to determine which part of the script is failing (are you successfully receiving the POST information, are you connecting to the database successfully, etc?)?

Comment: thank you for the error code I didn't know about it

Comment: On a side note, using `mysqli_` functions is a good step but not enough to prevent SQL injection. You need to use parameterized queries as the code above is subject to injection.

Comment: it won't display any errors but nothing has been added to the database

Comment: hi, what is $_POST['formsubmitted'] ? Have you checked whether you are reaching validation first?

Comment: sorry I have already got it to work

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The If conditions you have written is always retrun false.

To Resolve this Please set the name attribute of submit button to `formsubmitted` like as follows

```
<input id="register_submit" name= "formsubmitted" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
```

Since the `formsubmitted` is not present inside the form the values is not set for `$_POST['formsubmitted']`, So the `If part` of your if statement is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar script I often use, feel free to alter it at your discretion.

```
<? 
  if ($_POST['submit']){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

if (!$username || !$password || !$confirm || !$email){
    $response = "Please fill in all the boxes";
}else{

    $check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"));
    if ($check != 0){
        $response = "Username taken, Please choose an alternative";
    }else{

    $check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'"));
    if ($check != 0){
        $response = "This Email has already been registered";
    }else{


            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$email');");
$response = "Account Created";

}
}
}
}

echo "$response"; ?>
```

Comment: This isn't a login system, this cracks your site wide open. You haven't [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) anything so it's full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/), you're using MD5 for passwords which is severely wrong, and you're also using the deprecated, super terrible `mysql_query` interface. Please delete this answer. Additionally, I'd check to see if any sites you've deployed this on have been hacked because that would take about two seconds.